Delphi and REST with two methods with and without authenticate
I need REST service whit two methods: first need autorization and second open for all (with no authenticate procedure).
If I put TDSHttpService and bind with TDSAuthenticationManager, then all methods needs authenticate (in authentication event I have no info about method).
If I put two TDSHttpService components - one with and second without Auth Manager, and with different contexts (f.ex.), then can work together (on same port).
What is valid solution?

If I understand you correctly, you can't (have two services listening on the same port). You either need to use different ports, or integrate the code into the same service (detecting authenticated/unauthenticated f.ex. by the presence/absence of username+password/token and act accordingly).

Best: I will one service but with two categories - methods can be executed by authorized users and methods can be executed by any. But in authentication component don't know, which method is called.

The TDSAuthenticationManager has two events: OnUserAuthenticate and OnUserAuthorize. Inside the Authenticate event you check the user name and password. If valid add a special role (f.i. 'MainUser') to UserRoles. In both cases set valid to True;
You can now handle authorization in the other event, but there is a much easier way to do that: Add a [TRoleAuth('MainUser')] attribute to all the methods requiring authentication.
